# Can we find color of text present in button using appium ?

Tags: automation, appium, mobile-application

Is it possible to find the color of text present on a button using Appium ??

Ex :

If login button text has black or red or blue color can we find which is color of text on login button.

Comment: What kind of application is it? native, hybrid or web based mobile application?

Comment: For android its Hybrid. For iOS its Native.

Answer (score 1):

Appium is just hooking into some structure that's available to it i.e. the DOM on a mobile web application. It can't generate visual information like color unless it's accessible to you through code somehow.
For native applications, that will be your development team making the information available through the accessibility information.

Answer (score 1):

For Andriod where the application is hybrid type, you can extract css values of the elements using GetCssValue.

In C# it is as below

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.id("by-id"));
Console.WriteLine(elem.GetCssValue("color");
```

Also try to switch to webview context as below , then webdriver commands would all work like any desktop browser

```
   foreach(String context in driver.contexts())
    {
       if(context.contains("WebView"){
        driver.context = context;
        }
    }
```

If you do not get webview context, then the capability automationName needs to be assigned selendroid for an hybrid app